# How to extend the period between which stripe cancels an incomplete payment intent

Tags: stripe-payments

I set up stripe to receive payments after a user registers on my website. Some customers click the button to pay and then leave before they actually submit their card details. On the stripe dashboard, this transaction is marked as incomplete for 24 hours and then its status changes to cancel. I would like:

1. Extend the period before the payment intent is cancelled
2. Email the link to pay to them

Does anyone know how to accomplish this? Please help

Comment: You can't extend that period, there's no support for that. As for emailing them, that's something you'd have to build separate from Stripe I think. Like when the user visits your site , ask them for their email, and then redirect them to Checkout. If your system hasn't seen a webhook for a successful payment from that email address after a while, email them. (I would mail them a link to a page on your site that just attempts a brand new payment rather than trying to re-use the incomplete payment, it's easier).

Comment: Thanks, @karllekko, This is helpful. I will rather generate an invoice with a custom due date and then have stripe send it to the customer for execution